# My Button_click event is not firing in datalist

Tags: asp.net

Back End(Aspx.CS) This Event is Not Firing

```
protected void btnCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button b = sender as Button;
    if(b!=null)
    {
         name = b.CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("/Cart.aspx");
    }
}
```

Front End(Aspx Code) :

```
<asp:DataList ID="ItemList" runat="Server" CaptionAlign="Right" RepeatColumns="4" Width="100%" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Bind("Image")%>' alt='Image Not Visible' Style="height: 200px; width: 200px;" />
      <div class="caption">
       <h4>
         <asp:Label ID="ufname" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>'>l</asp:Label></h4>
         <p class="text-success">Rs:<asp:Label ID="ufprice" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Money") %>'></asp:Label></p>
         <p>
           <asp:Button ID="btnCart" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="Server" Text="Buy Now"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClick="btnCart_Click"/>
           <asp:Button ID="Veiw" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Details.." CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnClick="btnCart_Click"  />
         </p>         
       </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: did you have `!IsPostBack` while binding the datalist?Also better to use `ItemCommand` and define `CommandName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set EnableEventValidation to false?
Do you use any kind of UpdatePanel?

Comment: This feels more like a comment than a proper answer.

Comment: After setting EnableEventValidation to false it worked thanks

Comment: No problem @DakshJain Feel free to mark my comment as a solution.